# Refresh div tag in child component lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, es6

I am sending a value from a parent component to child inside div but it is not showing any value after first time

**Parent js**

```js
startRecording(){
    this.isRecording = !this.isRecording;
    if (this.isRecording) {
        this.iconName = "utility:unmuted";
        start();
    } else {
        this.iconName = "utility:muted";
        stop();
    }
    if(this.transcript){
        this.messageBody = this.transcript;
    }
}
```

from here I am sending the value to child using this:
**Parent HTML**

```
<c-textarea-file-drop
    file={file}
    onfileload={handleFileLoad}
    ontextchange={handleTextChange}
    voice-message={transcript}>
</c-textarea-file-drop>
```

**Child HTML**

```html
<div contenteditable="true"
    oninput={handleTextInput}
    onpaste={handlePaste}
    style="white-space: pre;">
        {voiceMessage}
</div>
```

**Child JS**

```js
@api voiceMessage;

handleTextInput() {
    console.log('voiceMessage--'+this.voiceMessage);
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('textchange', {
        detail: this.template.querySelector('[contenteditable]').textContent
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your textarea component inside template if true/ false.

Check the below code:

**Parent HTML**

```
<template if:true={transcript}>
     <c-textarea-file-drop file={file} onfileload={handleFileLoad} ontextchange={handleTextChange} voice-message={transcript}></c-textarea-file-drop>
</template>
<template if:false={transcript}>
     <c-textarea-file-drop file={file} onfileload={handleFileLoad} ontextchange={handleTextChange}></c-textarea-file-drop>
</template>
```